# read.xls() from gdata package fails with "no lines available in input"

Tags: r

I am using `read.xls()` from the `gdata` package to read Excel workbooks where each workbook has one sheet. The read fails with the following error.

```
> read.xls(list.files[[1]])
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

I can't figure out the error. `sheetCount()` returns the following error.

```
> sheetCount(list.files[[1]])
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 161 did not have 13 elements
```

But this is odd, because the workbook has 27 columns. And nothing seems out of the ordinary for rows 161+/-1 or columns 13+/-1.

Throughout the workbook repeated entries are blank and you're expected to manually extend them down (which is impractical for the 750+ workbooks that I would like to read).

I tried manually setting `quote=''` and `quote='\''`, but these don't change the output. Is my problem that `read.xls()` sees some rows as ragged but not others? Any pointers? (I tried the `xlsReadWrite` package, but I am on 64bit Win 7 and it only works on 32bit systems).

Thanks!

---

Update

I followed @G. Grothendieck's suggestions and get the following.

```
> k <- count.fields(xls2csv(list.xls[[1]]), sep = ","); k
NULL
> L <- readLines(xls2csv(list.xls[[1]])); L
character(0)
```

The temp file that `xls2csv()` generates is empty, so now I can't figure out why my `countSheets()` call returns the "line 161, column 13" error.

I also followed @Joran's suggestions and converted the .xls file to a .csv file in Libre Office and it converts and reads just fine (i.e., it counts 27 fields in all 236 lines and logical `readLines()` output).

---

Update 2

I should add that I *think* that these .xls files are *not* generated by Excel (my source is a little secretive about their origin), but I don't get any errors or warnings when I open them in Libre Office.

Comment: Impossible to tell without the xls file. I see in your future some quality time hunting for the unusual characters hidden somewhere in the xls file. A first step might be to export one as a csv and then try reading that into R, or open it in a text editor and visually scan it for anything unusual.

Comment: @joran -- Thanks for the pointer! I converted the .xls to a .csv in Libre Office and the conversion goes through and I can read with `read.csv()` and get logical entries for all rows and columns. I may be manually converting all .xls to .csv :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it suggests anything:

```
library(gdata)
k <- count.fields(xls2csv("myfile.xls"), sep = ","); k
L <- readLines(xls2csv("myfile.xls")); L
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and new tools! I updated my question and it looks like `xls2csv()` generates an empty .csv file. But now I can't understand why I get the odd `readLines()` error (i.e., about row 161 and column 13).

Comment: I went with the command line LibreOffice solution, but this is the best way to troubleshoot the problem (here I think it's because, for some reason, the Perl script can't convert the .xls file, although LibO can). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I think the problem is that the .xls to .csv Perl script fails (this is what `gdata` uses). I am still not sure why because LibreOffice converts the .xls to .csv with no warnings. I inspected the .csv with Vim and it looks normal (i.e., no crazy characters). I think the .xls is poorly formed by some proprietary script, so the Perl script fails.

Because LibreOffice works here, the easiest solution is to use command line LibreOffice (i.e., non of the Perl-based tools will work). I am on Win7, so I wrote a simple .bat file that converts every .xls in a directory.

```
for %%f in (*.xls) do soffice.exe -invisible -convert-to csv "%%f"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use XLConnect !

```
library(XLConnect)
readWorksheetFromFile(list.files[[1]], 1, useCachedValues=TRUE)
```

Comment: After the approach using `count.fields` along with `xls2csv` failed for a multi-sheet _*.xlsx_ file and `read.xlsx` kept on returning a "no lines available in input" error (although there were lines available), I tried this approach and it just worked out fine!